# Why some rows are missing in my recursive CTE?

Tags: postgresql, cte

These are my 2 tables `id_hierarchy` and `hierarchy_link`:

```
CREATE TABLE id_hierarchy
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    hierarchy integer
);
insert into id_hierarchy values (11,2),(22,3),(44,5),(77,8),(170,11),
(190,13),(240,18),(255,20);

CREATE TABLE hierarchy_link
(
    hid integer NOT NULL,
    parent_hid integer
);
insert into hierarchy_link values (1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(5,3),(8,5),(11,8),
(13,11),(15,13),(18,15),(20,18);
```

With `id_hierarchy.hierarchy`=`hierarchy_link.hid`

For the below CTE query:

```
with recursive rt1 as(
    select id,hid,parent_hid||'->'||hid as str 
    from rt2 
    where rt2.parent_hid=1
    union
    select t.id,t.hid,s.str||'->'||t.hid as str 
    from rt2 t 
    inner join rt1 s on (s.hid=t.parent_hid)
),
rt2 as (
    select id, hid, parent_hid, hierarchy 
    from hierarchy_link h 
    inner join id_hierarchy u on (u.hierarchy=h.hid)
)
select id, hid, str as hierarchy 
from rt1 
order by 1
```

I am getting this result:

```
id;  hid; hierarchy
11;  2;   "1->2"
22;  3;   "1->2->3"
44;  5;   "1->2->3->5"
77;  8;   "1->2->3->5->8"
170; 11;  "1->2->3->5->8->11"
190; 13;  "1->2->3->5->8->11->13"
```

Rows `240,18` and `255,20` are missing from `id_hierarchy`.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we slice your query, the first cte (`rt2`) returns this:

```
id   hid     parent_hid  hierarchy
11    2         1            2
22    3         2            3
44    5         3            5
77    8         5            8
170  11         8           11
190  13         11          13
240  18         15          18
255  20         18          20
```

The first `SELECT` ([root]) in the second cte (`rt1`) returns this:

```
id   hid     parent_hid  hierarchy
11    2         1            2
```

This is indeed the only row with `parent_hid = 1`. The recursive CTE starts with this single value and goes all the way down the hierarchy until there is no match anymore.

From this, the second `SELECT` recursively joins `rt2` with `rt1` on `rt1.hid = rt2.parent_id`:

```
id   hid     parent_hid  hierarchy
11    2         1            2 -+                1->2                   => start 
22    3         2            3 -+ -+             1->2->3                => previous + 3
44    5         3            5    -+ -+          1->2->3->5             => previous + 5
77    8         5            8       -+ -+       1->2->3->5->8          => previous + 8
170  11         8           11          -+ -+    1->2->3->5->8->11      => previous + 11
190  13         11          13             -+    1->2->3->5->8->11->13  => breaks here
240  18         15          18
255  20         18          20
```

It breaks on 190 because there is no match on `parent_hid = 13` where `hid = 13` (row for `id = 190`).

It breaks because your are only looking for hierarchy starting with a root at 1.

I am not sure what your expected output should be but if you are looking for hierarchies with no parent (i.e. `parent_hid` not in `hid` [the root]), you will also get the hierarchy `15->18->20`.

Replace `where rt2.parent_hid=1` by `WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM rt2 WHERE hid = r.parent_hid)` and starting roots will be:

```
id  hid hierarchy
11  2   1->2
240 18  15->18
```

And output will be:

```
id  hid hierarchy
11  2   1->2
22  3   1->2->3
44  5   1->2->3->5
77  8   1->2->3->5->8
170 11  1->2->3->5->8->11
190 13  1->2->3->5->8->11->13
240 18  15->18
255 20  15->18->20
```

It seems that only `hierarchy_link` is needed to built up the hierarchy. Therefore rt2 should be remove:

```
;WITH rt1 AS (
    SELECT hid, parent_hid, CAST(parent_hid as varchar(50)) + '->' + CAST(hid as varchar(50)) as [str] 
    FROM hierarchy_link r
    WHERE r.parent_hid = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l.hid, l.parent_hid, CAST(r.[str] as varchar(50)) + '->' + CAST(l.hid as varchar(50)) as [str] 
    FROM hierarchy_link l
    INNER JOIN rt1 r ON r.hid = l.parent_hid
)
SELECT h.id, r.hid, r.[str] as hierarchy 
FROM rt1 r
INNER JOIN id_hierarchy h ON h.hierarchy = r.hid;
```

The `id` from `id_hierarchy` is only added at the end once the hierarchy from `rt1` is ready:

```
id  hid hierarchy
11  2   1->2
22  3   1->2->3
44  5   1->2->3->5
77  8   1->2->3->5->8
170 11  1->2->3->5->8->11
190 13  1->2->3->5->8->11->13
240 18  1->2->3->5->8->11->13->15->18
255 20  1->2->3->5->8->11->13->15->18->20
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans, I modified the rt2 part inner_join as left_join and got the required result.

Answer (score 0):

With this modified query

```
with recursive rt1 as(
    select id,hid,parent_hid||'->'||hid as str 
    from rt2 
    where rt2.parent_hid=1
    union
    select t.id,t.hid,s.str||'->'||t.hid as str 
    from rt2 t 
    inner join rt1 s on (s.hid=t.parent_hid)
),
rt2 as (
    select id, hid, parent_hid, hierarchy 
    from hierarchy_link h 
    left join id_hierarchy u on (u.hierarchy=h.hid)
)
select id, hid, str as hierarchy 
from rt1 where id is not null
order by 1
```

I got the required result,

```
id  hid hierarchy
11  2   1->2
22  3   1->2->3
44  5   1->2->3->5
77  8   1->2->3->5->8
170 11  1->2->3->5->8->11
190 13  1->2->3->5->8->11->13
240 18  1->2->3->5->8->11->13->15->18
255 20  1->2->3->5->8->11->13->15->18->20
```